# Yet Another crosdomain.xml question or: "How to interpret documentation correctly"

Tags: apache-flex, flash, cross-domain, crossdomain.xml

I have read a lot about the new policy-policy of flash player and also know the master policy file.
Now image the following situation:
There are two servers with services (http) running at custom ports

- servera.com:2222/websiteA
- serverb.com:3333/websiteB

Now I open a swf from server a (eg. servera.com:2222/websiteA/A.swf) that wants to access the service of serverb.
Of course I need a crossdomain.xml at the right place and there are multiple variations possible.
I dont want to use a master policy file, as I might not have control over the root of both servers.

One solution I found works with the following crossdomain:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-access-from domain="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

served at `serverb.com:3333/websiteB/crossdomain.xml`

So now for my question:
Is it possible to get rid of the `"*"` and use a proper (not as general as `*`) domainname in the allow-access-from rule?
All my attempts failed, and from what I understand it should be possible.

Comment: What were your attempts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM
"http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">

<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-access-from domain="*.servera.com" to-ports="3333"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

(you may have to specify the port for the from domain as well - I haven't had to deal w/ cross domain w/ ports in a while.

Comment: What do you mean with "specify the port for the from domain"? I didnt find an attribute like "from-ports" in the specs. Is there another way that I am not aware of?

Comment: there's not a from ports, i meant like domain="*.servera.com:3333"

Answer (score 0):

Be very careful with crossdomain policy files.  If you are using cookie auth or if serverb.com is on an internal network then you should not use a crossdomain policy.  Alternatively you can use a proxy on servera.com that proxies the requests to serverb.com.  That would avoid the crossdomain request.

You should also setup logging using an mm.cfg file containing:

```
ErrorReportingEnable=1
TraceOutputFileEnable=1
PolicyFileLog=1
PolicyFileLogAppend=1
```

That will log the errors to a text file.  Check out more [details on setting up the mm.cfg file](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/client_debug_03.html).

Comment: True - I'd also get the current cross domain policy file down ASAP as it's basically allowing everything.

Comment: I think I am fully aware of the risks, nevertheless, thanks James for pointing that out to everyone. I also think a proxy should be the solution of choice. Still, the initial question remains open.

Comment: If it is safe for you to use a crossdomain policy file because serverb.com does not use cookie auth and isn't an internal server then it's probably also ok to leave the "*" in there.

Are you getting an error message in a debug version of Flash Player?

Comment: I am very very confused now, as it works on some systems with some browsers and on others it fails. I cant make no sense out of it. E.g. Safari under OSX always refuses the corssdomain except for the "*" one and IE on WinXP always accepts it, no matter what kind of (well formed) rubbish I put in the file. Maybe one time I will find out what exactly is going on under the hood, but for now I stick with the "*" for development and use a proxy for life systems.
Thanks for your help, esp. the port variant from quoo, I think that "should" be the solution.

Comment: I've added some info on how to debug policy errors.  Getting an error message goes a long way in determining what the problem is.